# why does realloc doesn' t return contiguos memory blocks?? or what's going on

Tags: c

i made this function that allocates character by character a string

```
unsigned int kts (char **par) {
    
    char *string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); *string = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    if (string) string[0] = getchar();
    for(i = 1; string && string[i - 1] != '\n'; i++) 
        string = (char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2)), string[i] = getchar();
    string[i] = '\0';
    
    
    *par = string;
    
    return i;
}
```

and used it for allocating character by character a vector of strings

```
for (k = 1; ver && string && *string; k++) {
    sum += kts(&string[k - 1]);

    if (strstr(string[k-1],".\n"))
        ver = 0;
    else
        *string = (char *)realloc(*string, (sizeof (char)) * (sum + 1)), string = (char **)realloc(string, sizeof(char*) * (k + 1)), string[k] = *string + ((sum + 1) * sizeof **string);
}
```

and it allows me to acces to the elements like this

```
for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
    
    for (j = 0; string[i][j]; j++){
        
        if (isalnum(string[i][j]))
            alnum++;
        if (isalnum(string[i][j]) && (!j || !isalnum(string[i][j - 1])))
            par++;
    }
}
```

i was expecting being able to acces in this way to the elements of the array

```
for (i = 0; i < sum + k - 1; i++) {
    
putchar((*string)[i]);
    if (isalnum((*string)[i]))
        alnum++;
    if (isalnum((*string)[i]) && (!i || !isalnum((*string)[i - 1])))
        par++;
    
}
```

but it gives garbage values even though it seems that memory was succesfully allocated in a previous call but was freed from realloc and now is a dangling pointer.

i edited the code and still doesnt works as intended but it doesn't loop until EOF. there you have the full story thanks by the advice on the coma operator :)

```
unsigned int kts (char **par) {

char *string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); *string = 0;
unsigned int i;
if (string) string[0] = getchar();

for(i = 1; string && string[i - 1] != '\n'; i++) {
    string = (char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2));
    string[i] = getchar();
}   string[i] = '\0';


*par = string;

return i; }


int main () {

unsigned int sum = 0, k = 0, cent = 1, i = 0, alnum = 0, par = 0, j = 0;
char **string = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)), ver = 1;


for (k = 1; ver && string && *string; k++) {
    sum += kts(&string[k - 1]);

    if (strstr(string[k-1],".\n"))
        ver = 0;
    else
        *string = (char *)realloc(*string, (sizeof (char)) * (sum + 1)), string = (char **)realloc(string, sizeof(char*) * (k + 1)), string[k] = *string + ((sum + 1) * sizeof **string);
}

puts("");

for (i = 0; i < sum + k - 1; i++) {

putchar((*string)[i]);
if (isalnum((*string)[i]))
    alnum++;
if (isalnum((*string)[i]) && (!i || !isalnum((*string)[i - 1])))
    par++;

}

for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
    
    for (j = 0; string[i][j]; j++){
        
        if (isalnum(string[i][j]))
            alnum++;
        if (isalnum(string[i][j]) && (!j || !isalnum(string[i][j - 1])))
            par++;
    }
}
    
printf("\nStrings: %d, Characters: %d, Alphanum: %d, Words: %d", k - 1, sum, alnum, par);   


free(*string), string = NULL;
free(string), string = NULL;

return 0; }
```

Comment: `realloc` _always_ returns a pointer to a contiguous memory block - or `NULL`. It doesn't look like you are checking the return value at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre] from your code snippets. Preferably use one code block we can copy, paste, compile and run to reproduce the problem. Also add the input you use, the actual output you get and the expected output as text, formatted as code blocks.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Obfuscation? The use of a comma, and the different levels of indirection you put `string` to.

Comment: @TedLyngmo They're checking it with `string &&` in the `for` loop condition.

Comment: This line of code is deadly **wrong**:  `string = (char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2)), string[i] = getchar();`  Oooof.  Who taught you to write code like that?  And what exactly do you think it does?

Comment: Note that there's no sequence point in the assignment operator. So reassigning `string` in the RHS when assigning to `*string` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, yes, but `*string = (char *)realloc(*string,...` is still not very good since it's assigning a new value to `*string` which may be `NULL`.

Comment: @Barmar True, but UB isn't required to explain the fact that the code simply doesn't work.  The UB is just a bonus feature.  The code needs to be compiled with all compiler warnings enabled.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Read that line again - the value from `realloc()` is never assigned to `string`...

Comment: @TedLyngmo That loop has `string && *string`. The code has problems, but null-safety isn't one of them.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, I thought `string` was a `char**` but see now that it's a `char*` so `*string = (char*)realloc(*string,...` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was referring to the use of `realloc()` in the first code snippet.  The bug there is a lot more subtle.  It looks like a comma operator was used there to cram two lines of code into one.  Lord only knows why someone would want to do that, though.  Hopefully this is a perfect lesson as to why cramming code into as few lines as possible is a **really BAD idea**.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it seems to be both: `string = (char *)realloc(...)` and  `string = (char **)realloc(...)` in different functions.

Comment: I didn't even scroll that far to the right where the real horror is revealed :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ow.  My eyes.

Answer (score 3):

This answer only addresses this code:

```
for(i = 1; string && string[i - 1] != '\n'; i++) 
    string = (char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2)), string[i] = getchar();
```

That code does not do what it was apparently meant to do.  It appears the comma operator was used to avoid having to use braces:

```
for(i = 1; string && string[i - 1] != '\n'; i++) 
{
    string = (char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2));
    string[i] = getchar();
}
```

But the equivalent code is actually this:

```
for(i = 1; string && string[i - 1] != '\n'; i++) 
{
    (void)(char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2));
    string = string[i] = getchar();
}
```

The value returned from `realloc()` is *discarded*, and the result of `string[i] = getchar()` is assigned to `string`.

Per [**6.5.17 Comma operator**, paragraph 2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17p2)

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

The result of `string[i] = getchar()` is the value returned from `getchar()` - which is what gets assigned to `string`.

Maybe.

There's no sequence point in that last `string = string[i] = getchar();` assignment - when `string` is dereferenced via `string[i]` in relation to the actual assignment of `string` is not defined by the C standard.

So not only is the value assigned to `string` not what was intended, the behavior of the code is undefined.

Note that

```
for(i = 1; string && string[i - 1] != '\n'; i++) 
{
    string = (char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2));
    string[i] = getchar();
}
```

still has problems - it will infinite loop on `EOF`.

Comment: Re “But the equivalent code is actually this:… `string = string[i] = getchar();`”: No, it is not. `a = b, c = d` is parsed as `(a = b), (c = d)`, not `a = (b, c = d)`.

Comment: Re “There's no sequence point in that last…”: No sequence point is needed, because C has other rules about sequencing. Even if it were parsed as `a = (b, c = d)`, the storing of the updated value of the left operand of an assignment is sequenced after value computations of the operands, per C 2018 6.5.16 3. So `string = string[i] = getchar();` would store the result of `getchar()` in `string[i]` using the value of `string` before the update.

Answer (score 1):

The use of comma instead of curly braces has been addressed and won't be repeated here.

There are a number of other shortcomings and problems that are worthy of /* commenting */ about in the original version of the OP's code:

```
unsigned int kts (char **par) { // "unsigned int" could be simply "unsigned"

/* 1. In C we don't cast the return from malloc() (and its variations)
 * 2. Stacking 2 lines into one makes both difficult to read.
 * 3. The verification that malloc() didn't fail is hidden in the code.
 * 4. Poorly formatted. Inconsistent indentation.
 */
char *string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); *string = 0;
unsigned int i;
if (string) string[0] = getchar();

for(i = 1; string && string[i - 1] != '\n'; i++) {
/* "sizeof(char)" is defined to be 1. 1*anything = anything. */
    string = (char *)realloc(string, (sizeof (char)) * (i + 2));
    string[i] = getchar();
}   string[i] = '\0'; // STACKING code again. Difficult to read!
/* That last line is dangerous and shows why you need to think carefully.
 * Consider the user types an empty line (ie. just '\n')
 * The for() loop doesn't run even once, but the value of 'i' is 1.
 * There is an allocated buffer of 1 byte (ie. string[0]).
 * Setting string[1] to '\0' scribbles outside of the allocated buffer.
 */


*par = string;

return i; }


/* Should be "int main ( void ) {" */
int main () {

/* Declaring all variables at top of function is old style.
 * They become separated from their use.
 * Eg: "cent" is defined and initialised, but never used.
 * What is the purpose of 'i', 'k', 'j', 'par'?
 * Non-descriptive variable names are hard for the reader to keep straight
 */
unsigned int sum = 0, k = 0, cent = 1, i = 0, alnum = 0, par = 0, j = 0;

/* Tucked almost out of sight is 'ver = 1'... A single byte initialised to a constant? */
char **string = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)), ver = 1;

/* 'ver' appears again, and only with a lot of dissecting is its purpose discovered.
 * 'ver' is a flag used to break the loop when a condition occurs.
 * C provides 'break' to perform this operation.
 * In fact, the additional increment of 'k' creates another problem later.
 */
for (k = 1; ver && string && *string; k++) {
    sum += kts(&string[k - 1]);

    if (strstr(string[k-1],".\n"))
        ver = 0;
    else
/* No one wants to try to untangle what this run-on operation is trying to achieve!
 * Comments may help clarify, but its still too much...
 */
        *string = (char *)realloc(*string, (sizeof (char)) * (sum + 1)),
        string = (char **)realloc(string, sizeof(char*) * (k + 1)),
        string[k] = *string + ((sum + 1) * sizeof **string);
}


/* "putchar( '\n' );" would be more idiomatic */
puts(""); 

/* Ah, 'k' is +1 too much, so here there is "k - 1". */
for (i = 0; i < sum + k - 1; i++) {

putchar((*string)[i]);
/* Duplication of "isalnum( c )".
 * No instance of "isalnum( c )" casts the char to an unsigned char
 */
if (isalnum((*string)[i]))
    alnum++;
if (isalnum((*string)[i]) && (!i || !isalnum((*string)[i - 1])))
    par++;

}

/* It looks like THIS is the code to examine each row of the array of strings.
 * Not obvious what the previous loop was doing...
 * Hard to tell that it really was a loop. Bad indentation.
 */
for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
    
    for (j = 0; string[i][j]; j++){
        
        if (isalnum(string[i][j]))
            alnum++;
        if (isalnum(string[i][j]) && (!j || !isalnum(string[i][j - 1])))
            par++;
    }
}
    
/* Variable names do not match well with their titles, and
 * "%d" is not the correct format specifier for unsigned int. Use "%u".
 */
printf("\nStrings: %d, Characters: %d, Alphanum: %d, Words: %d", k - 1, sum, alnum, par);   

/* There should be a loop here "free()'ing" each of the strings in the array */
free(*string), string = NULL;
free(string), string = NULL;

return 0; } // unconventional
```

The formatting problems can be fixed by a modern IDE editor.

---

In the end, this code thrashes dynamic memory trying to take in one-or-more lines of text until one line ends with a period (eg: "... word.\n"). It then wants to scramble along each line while counting things.

Here is an offering of commented code that works. The first function (still using an unverified `realloc()`; forgive me, please) grabs all that it can until the condition of a line ending with ".\n". The entire entered text is returned as one continuous C string to the caller. The second function does the tallying and print required. Should it be necessary to do something else with each *line*, an array of pointers to each line could be quickly populated with `strtok( cp, "\n" );`. Left as an exercise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Accept characters until ".\n" (or EOF), adding each to growing dynamic array.
char *kts( void ) {
    char *str = NULL;
    unsigned i = 0;

    for( int ch, prev = 0; ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF; prev = ch ) {
        str = realloc( str, i + 2 ); // "realloc( NULL,..." same as "malloc("
        /* verification omitted for brevity */
        str[ i++ ] = (char)ch;
        if( prev == '.'  && ch == '\n' )
            break;
    }
    if( i ) 
        str[ i ] = '\0';

    return str; // may be NULL if EOF encountered immediately
}

/* Tally and print characteristics of this long string */
void xyz( char *cp ) {
    unsigned nln = 0, nbyt = 0, nchr = 0, nwrd = 0;

    // "transition" if no non-alpha's before first "word"
    nwrd += !!isalnum( (unsigned char)cp[ 0 ] ); 

    // byte count is loop counter
    for( nbyt = 0; cp[ nbyt ]; nbyt++ ) {
        if( isalnum( (unsigned char)cp[ nbyt ] ) ) {
            nchr++; // alphanumeric char counter

            // transitioning into a word??
            nwrd += (nbyt && !isalnum( (unsigned char)cp[ nbyt - 1 ] ) ); 
        }
        else
            nln += cp[ nbyt ] == '\n'; // count number of LF chars
    }
    printf( "%u lines, %u chars, %u alphanum, %u words\n", nln, nbyt, nchr, nwrd );
}

int main( void ) {
    char *cp = kts();
    if( cp == NULL )
        exit(1);

    printf( "::BEGIN::\n%s:::END:::\n", cp );
    xyz( cp );

    // Could use strtok() here to create array of pointers to each line.
    // Usual caution: strtok() treats consecutive delimiters as one delimiter.

    free( cp );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
one two three
four.
::BEGIN::
one two three
four.
:::END:::
2 lines, 19 chars, 14 alphanum, 4 words
```

Comment: Wdym with unverified realloc() is not reliable as a function??

Comment: im there's a reason the documentation says, in every page I've read, system calls (like `realloc()`) can fail. Eg... Trying to allocate 42TB of storage on a machine with 16GB of RAM and a 1TB of SSD... ALWAYS check return codes... Always... (except for demo programs.)